# Proving that $0\cdot x=0$ using field axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the following axiomatic definition of a field:

> A *field* is a set $F$ together with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ on $F$ such that $(F,+)$ is an Abelian group with identity $0$ and $(F\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is an Abelian group with identity $1$, and the following left-distributive law holds: $$a\cdot(b+c)=(a\cdot b)+(a\cdot c)\quad\forall a,b,c\in F.$$

I want to show that $0\cdot x=0$ for any $x\in F$ using these, **and only these**, field axioms. I can prove that $x\cdot 0=0$ using left-distributivity, but multiplication with $0$ is not necessary commutative *a priori* [that $(F\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is an Abelian group does not say anything about multiplication with $0$].

Any hint would be appreciated.

---

To elaborate on my point, let me prove that $x\cdot 0=0$ for any $x\in F$:
\begin{align*}
0+0=&\,0\\
\Downarrow&\,\\
x\cdot(0+0)=&\,x\cdot0\\
\Downarrow&\,\text{(left-distributivity)}\\
(x\cdot 0)+(x\cdot 0)=&\,x\cdot 0\\
\Downarrow&\,\\
[(x\cdot 0)+(x\cdot 0)]+[-(x\cdot 0)]=&\,x\cdot 0+[-(x\cdot 0)]\\
\Downarrow&\,\\
(x\cdot0)+\{(x\cdot0)+[-(x\cdot0)]\}=&\,0\\
\Downarrow&\,\\
(x\cdot0)+0=&\,0\\
\Downarrow&\,\\
x\cdot0=&\,0.
\end{align*}
My problem is I would need to exploit right-distributivity to show that $0\cdot x=0$, but right-distributivity does not follow immediately from the axioms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't.

Let $F=\Bbb Q$, define addition as usual and $$x\cdot y =\begin{cases}xy&\text{if }x\ne 0\\y&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$$
Then

- $(F,+)$ is an abelian group because $\Bbb Q$ really is a field;
- $(F\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is an abelian group because $\Bbb Q$ really is a field and $\cdot $ conincides with standard multiplication here
- Left distribution holds for $a\ne 0$ because it holds in the field $\Bbb Q$
- left distribution holds for $a=0$ by direct verification

---

In other words: your collection of axioms is "wrong".

Comment: Thank you very much. FWIW, this definition comes from the celebrated textbook by [Dummit and Foote (2004, p. 34)](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471433349.html). Apparently, the condition “$(F\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is an Abelian group” should be complemented as “$(F\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is an Abelian group and $\cdot$ is commutative on the whole of $F$.”

Comment: @triple_sec Gross! But I just found it's allready in the [errata](http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~foote/errata_3rd_edition.pdf) (of which there seem to be quite a few beyond typoes). - Back at school I complained that the textbook we had forgot to require $1\ne 0$ in its field axioms and my teacher didn't believe me it was important ...

Comment: Thank you for the link to the errata sheet. Indeed, if $1=0$, then $X=\{0\}$. However, many algebraists don’t regard this “trivial field” as a _bona fide_ field. [On a related note: My pet peeve is how the important qualifier “non-trivial” is often left out of the statement “every vector space has a basis in ZFC.” Really? Please give me a basis for $\{0\}$ then...]

Comment: @triple_sec: Here you go: $\{\}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm But $\operatorname{span}\varnothing=\varnothing\neq\{0\}$. The empty set doesn’t span anything.

Comment: @triple_sec: No, $\operatorname{span}\varnothing$ is $\{0\}$. The span is the set of all linear combinations, _including_ the empty linear combination (which in this case is the only one).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I guess it’s a matter of interpretation. To me, $$\operatorname{span} S=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mathbf{b}_i\,\Bigg|\,n\in\mathbb N,(a_i,\mathbf b_i)\in\mathbb F\times S\text{ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$}\right\}.$$ If anything were in the span of the empty set, then that thing would be a linear combination of _some_ elements from the empty set, but the empty set has no elements.

Comment: @triple_sec: I agree with that defintion. No matter which set $S$ is, the zero vector will arise by setting $n=0$, resulting in the empty sum.

Comment: @HenningMakholm OK, I see. Your definition conforms nicely to the existence of bases even for the trivial vector space. I’m nevertheless still reluctant to accept the convention that the span of the empty set is not empty, yet I do realize, as I read more about it, that this convention is standard in linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

What you are calling "commutativity" is "distributivity". While only "left-distributivity" is defined, multiplication in a field **is** commutative.  Once you have shown that x0= 0, it follows immediately from the commutativity of multiplication that 0x= 0.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the mistakes. That’s the whole point: that $x\cdot 0=0$ does _not_ imply that $0\cdot x=0$, because $\cdot$ is commutative **only on** $F\setminus\{0\}$ according to the axioms I presented! @HagenvonEitzen pointed out my axioms are not right, and are compatible with multiplication not being commutative.